# How to access to element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to access the value of message "Meeting 9943...is not found or has expired"

I tried:

```
                if (response.data.status == 404) {
                    angular.element(document.getElementById("msg")).css("color", "red");
                    $scope.msg = response.data.message.message; <- this show undefined
                    console.log("Status Code= " + response.data.status + ", Status Text= " + response.data.message);
                    return false;
                }
```

[image: watch]

What is the correct method to access the value of response.data.message.message?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the message is a string, you need to parse it with:

```
JSON.parse(response.data.message)
```

And after that, you can access to the property message inside the object.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Garcia - How does the code for this looks? Something like: var r = JSON.parse(response.data.message), and then $scope.msg = r.message; - ??

Comment: Yeah, you can perform let messageObject = JSON.parse(response.data.message); and then you can access to messageObject.message and assign the result to another variable to be used later.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct syntax, are you sure this debug snapshot is for the object you are getting the error on?

Try

`$scope.msg = response.data.message && response.data.message.message;`

this will not try and access the message for cases where the parent message object doesn't exist.